# Is it possible to conditionally apply annotation in an annotation?

Tags: java, annotations, java-annotations

I'm trying to do something like the following:

```
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface AnnotationOne {
    boolean annotationTwoToggler() default false

    {
        if (annotationTwoToggler) {
            // Apply annotation AnnotationTwo to calling type
        }
    }
}
```

An example of how I would use this:

```
@AnnotationOne(true) // Implies AnnotationTwo
public class MyClass { ... }
```

`AnnotationTwo` and its implementations are in the API that I'm using, and cannot be changed. I want to cause all implementations of `AnnotationTwo` to trigger given a `true` parameter to `AnnotationOne`.

How can I do this?

Comment: yes, but the if(annotationTwoToggler) part doesn't go in the annotation, it goes in the class with the code that handles the logic behind it

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: what exactly is your annotation supposed to trigger? validation? aop code?

Comment: AnnotationOne should be mainly semantic, though when passed true, AnnotationTwo would tell other classes to ignore the annotated class when searching for other classes of its nature. Code for AnnotationTwo already exists. (It's part of the API)